# Travelling on last day of Multiple Entry Schengen visa

Tags: multiple-entry, visa-expiration, hungary

My Multiple entry Schengen Visa (from Portugal embassy) is expiring on the 2nd of June 2019. I have to travel to Hungary (Budapest) on 2nd June. Is it possible to travel to Hungary on 2nd June, with new Schengen visa with validity from 3rd June?

Comment: Budapest is in Hungary not the Czech Republic, are you travelling through on the way to Budapest?

Comment: I am travelling to Budapest on 2nd June